# Binary to Text File Conversion in C

Tags: c

This is the code I have so far for the binary conversion:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned long binaryToDecimal(char *binary, int length);
void binaryToText(char *binary, int binaryLength, char *text, int symbolCount);
void formatBinary(char *input, int length, char *output);
int validate(char *binary);

int main(void)
{
    char binary[8063];
    int binaryLength;

    scanf("%8063[^\n]s", binary);
    binaryLength = strlen(binary);
    if(validate(binary))
    {
        int symbolCount = binaryLength / 8 + 1;
        char *text = malloc(symbolCount + 1);
        char *formattedBinary = malloc(binaryLength + 1);
        if(text == NULL || formattedBinary == NULL)
            exit(1);
        if(binaryLength % 8 == 0)
            --symbolCount;

        formatBinary(binary, binaryLength, formattedBinary);
        binaryToText(formattedBinary, strlen(formattedBinary), text, symbolCount);
        printf("%s in binary is the following text:\n%s\n", binary, text);

        free(text);
        free(formattedBinary);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The input should be a binary number, containing only zeros(0) and ones(1).\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void binaryToText(char *binary, int binaryLength, char *text, int  symbolCount)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < binaryLength; i+=8, binary += 8)
    {
        char *byte = binary;
        byte[8] = '\0';
        *text++ = binaryToDecimal(byte, 8);
    }
    text -= symbolCount;
}

unsigned long binaryToDecimal(char *binary, int length)
{
    int i;
    unsigned long decimal = 0;
    unsigned long weight = 1;
    binary += length - 1;
    weight = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i, --binary)
    {
        if(*binary == '1')
        decimal += weight;
        weight *= 2;
    }

    return decimal;
}

void formatBinary(char *input, int length, char *output)
{
    while(*input)
    {
        if(*input == '0' || *input == '1')
        {
            *output++ = *input++;
        }
        else
        {
            ++input;
            --length;
        }
    }
    output -= length;
}

int validate(char *binary)
{
    while(*binary)
    {
        if((*binary != '0') && (*binary != '1') && (*binary != ' '))
        return 0;
        ++binary;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Binary File:

010000010100000100110100001100110010000001000100010001100101011100100000010001000101010001010111001000000011001000110000001100010011011000101101001100000011000100101101001100000011011000100000001100010011000100111010001100000011000000001101000010100100000101000001001101000011001100100000010001000100011001010111001000000100010001010100010101110010000000110010001100000011000100110110001011010011000000110001001011010011000100110111001000000011000100110001001110100011000000110000000011010000101001000001010000010011010000110100001000000101001101000101010000010010000001001010010001100100101100100000001100100011000000110001001101010010110100110000001100100010110100110000001101010010000000110111001110100011010000110101000011010000101001000001010000010011000100111001001101110010000001001111010100100100010000100000010000100100111101010011001000000011001000110000001100010011001000101101001100000011001100101101001100010011001000100000001100010011000100111010001101010011000000100000000011010000101001000001010000010011000100100000010010100100011001001011001000000100110001000001010110000010000000110010001100000011000100110110001011010011000000110111001011010011000000110010001000000011100100111010001100000011000000001101000010100100111101001111001101110011010000110011001101010010000001000100010101000101011100100000010100000100110001001110001000000011001000110000001100010011011000101101001100010011000100101101001100100011001000100000001100100011000100111010001101010011010100001101000010100100011000111001001101100011000100110010001000000100010001000101010011100010000001001101010010010100000100100000001100100011000000110001001101000010110100110001001100100010110100110001001110010010000000110010001100100011101000110001001101010000110100001010010001000100110000111000001100000011000100100000010001110100010101000111001000000100110101010011010100000010000000110010001100000011000100110110001011010011000000111000001011010011001100110001001000000011100100111010001100000011000000001101000010100100010001001100001100010011000000111000001101110010000001000001010101000100110000100000010001000100000101000010001000000011001000110000001100010011011000101101001100000011010000101101001100010011000000100000001100010011001000111010001100000011010100001101000010100100010001001100001110000011001000111000001000000100100101000001010010000010000001010011010011000100001100100000001100100011000000110001001100100010110100110000001101100010110100110000001100100010000000110111001110100011010000110101

The  conversion algorithm itself works perfectly fine. My main question is how would you be able to apply that conversion to files themselves. Where the first file is a bin file and using the conversion will bring out a text file with all the binary numbers fully converted.

Comment: A platform-dependent solution would be to use file redirection.  (`# myprog < binary.bin > text.txt`)

Comment: Note that your input is not really a binary file as most people use the term. It's a text file, but the text consists only of binary digits.

Comment: Open the input file with `fopen()`, read it with `fscanf()`. Open the output file with `fopen()`, write to it with `fprintf()`.